# Division in looping

Tags: php, loops, division

I have problem with division in looping. I have a multiselect combo-box form which contains a lesson. This form is used to store teaching hours data for teachers . Each teacher may teach more than one lesson.

```
<form class="form-vertical" method="POST" action="http://localhost/penjadwalan/administrator/jammengajar/add_process">
<fieldset>
<legend>Tambah Data</legend>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="order">Guru</label>  
                       <input id="teacher" name="teacher" value="TI" type="text">
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="order">Mata Pelajaran</label>  
                       <select name="lesson[]" multiple class="form-control chosen-select">
                          <option value="108">Teknik Informatika - Prakarya</option>
                          <option value="107">Antropologi</option>
                          <option value="81">Sosiologi</option>
                          <option value="74">Seni Budaya</option>
                          <option value="70">Bahasa Sunda</option>
                          <option value="68">Seni Musik</option>
                          </select>          
            </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="order">Total Hours</label>  
                       <input id="total_jam" name="total_hours" value="" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
                    </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                        <button id="" name="" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Simpan Data</button>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Each lesson has a quota of hours ranging from 1 - 4. i will give an example

- teacher : andy
- lesson : math (4 hours),chemistry (2 hours)
- total hours : 30 hours

according data above, the teacher have 2 lessons. so, it should be 16 hours for math and 14 hours for chemistry..now how to automatically divide it base on total hours and lesson?

The process script that I made

```
if ($lesson > 1) {
$class = $total_hours / $lesson;

if ($class % 2 == 0) {
    $class = $class;
} else {
    $class = $class + 1;
    $remaining_class = $total / $lesson - 1; 
}
} else {
    $class = $total_hours;
}

if (count($lesson) > 1) {
    foreach ($lesson as $v) {
        $lesson_data = $this->pelajaran->getIdLesson($v);
        $class = $this->kelas->getAllClassByFaculty($mappel->kelompok_mapel)->result();
        $total_class = count($class);
        $n = $class / $lesson_data->jumlah_jam;
        foreach ($kelas_jurusan as $vals) {
            if ($i < $n) {
                $jammengajar = array('kode_guru' => $kode_guru,
                                     'id_mapel' => $mappel->id_mapel,
                                     'jumlah_jam' => $mappel->jumlah_jam,
                                     'id_kelas' => $vals->id_kelas
                                    );
                $this->jammengajar->addJamMengajar($jammengajar);
            } else {

            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
} else {

}
```

Comment: Can yo give more information on what the code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, there are multiple ways to do this.

**The simplest approach, treating it sort of like a vector:**

Add your hours for each class, divide by the total.  So from your example:

teacher : andy
lesson : math (4 hours),chemistry (2 hours)
total hours : 30 hours

You would take 30/(4 + 2) = 5, then multiply each class by the number value, which would give you 4*5=20 hours of math and 2*5=10 hours of chemistry.

The problem you'll run into with this or any solution is when the hours can't work (if that's a possible scenario), such as 31 hours, in which case you will want to take the "floor" value of your coefficient (ie, 31/(4+2)=5.16, so you'd still just do 5).

From there, you could take whatever remainder, check to see if it's smaller than the smaller class, and if so, fill up with the smaller class (with 32 hours, you would get 32/(4+2), which is 5.33333, floor that down to 5, then repeat with the remaining two hours, thus giving you 20 hours of math and 12 hours of chemistry).